# Vuejs. Очистка поля ввода

Tags: vue.js

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" v-model="message"></textarea>

 this.$emit('messageAdded', this.message);
 this.message = '';
```

значение message удаляется, но в форме остаётся прежним. Может кто-нибудь подсказать причину?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы либо [не добавили message в data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), либо в вызываемом контексте this не является интересующим компонентом vue.

Следующий код вполне себе работает:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  template: '#template',
  el: '#target',
  data: {
    message: null
  },
  watch: {
    message: function (value) {
      console.info('Message changed to:', value)
    }
  }
})
app.message = 'test'
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-template">
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
    <textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, опечатку нашёл. (date)